# Expose Log4net log through rss

Tags: c#, wcf, rss, log4net

I have a simple question which propably has a difficult answer, but what is the most straightforward way of exposing your Log4Net log through RSS?

I've come up with an idea to create an AdoAppender and expose some sort of wcf service to the log table. I've tried to Google for it, but until now i've come up with zero results.

Could anyone provide me with a starting point for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the AdoNetAppender and log in a database. Then it should be quite simple to create a feed. The following article shows the basics and all that is left for you is to load the data from the database:

http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/create-rss-2-0-and-atom-1-0-in-asp-net-3-5-csharp/

Comment: Thanks, this will get me on my way.